# Symfony2, twig template and @ORM\Table

Tags: symfony, doctrine, twig

I have an working application. Now I want to change the table names of my entities from CamelCase to underscore_case.

Old code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="FeaturedProduct")
 */
class FeaturedProduct
{ ... }
```

every thing works

New code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="featured_product")
 */
class FeaturedProduct
{ ... }
```

Now I get:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template:

> ("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myapp.FeaturedProduct' doesn't exist") in MyApp::layout_user_2_col.html.twig at line 37.

```
MyApp/Resources/views/layout_user_2_col.html.twig:37 
{% render "MyApp:FeaturedProduct:random" %}
```

The file MyApp/Resources/views/FeaturedProduct/random.html.twig exists.

It looks like twig is using the table name for the path of the templates instead of the name of the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error.

I used the name of the table in a native doctrine query in my FeaturedProduct repository. Changing this to take the table name dynamic solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have not updated your schema.

Use the following command to see what changes should be made in order to sync the schema and entities annotations:

> app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql

and run the following command to actualy make this changes

> app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Comment: executing the two commands gives me `Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata`.

If I change my model I always execute `doctrine:database:drop; doctrine:database:create; doctrine:schema:create; cache:clear`